# Почему нельзя вычесть итераторы у forward_list? C++

Tags: c++, список, итераторы, forward-list

Написал вот такой код:

```
std::forward_list flist{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << flist.begin() - flist.end() << "\n";
```

Почему компилятор выдает ошибку о том, что у итераторов нет оператора вычитания? С чем связано отсутствие возможности у однонаправленного связного списка вычесть итераторы?

Comment: С тем, что эти итераторы не являются итераторами произвольного доступа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С тем, что это итераторы категории `forward_iterator_tag`, у них нет оператора вычитания.

И это логично, потому что вычитание таких итераторов потребовало бы три (!) прохода по списку (определить номер элемента в списке для первого (первый проход) и второго (второй проход) элемента, потом найти в списке элемент, номер которого соответствует разности (третий проход)).

Чтобы подчеркнуть этот факт семантически, оператор убрали - иначе можно будет легким движением руки (заменой вектора н список) превратить приложение в тормозилку.

Comment: а вот третий проход что то странно выглядит

Comment: Да, можно ввести гениальную оптимизацию и все сделать в рамках одного прохода до самого дальнего элемента, но тогда придется делать больше сравнений на каждом шаге.

Comment: я понимаю, что можно за один проход все сделать. И это нормальный подход - просто бежим от начала до конца (у нас же особый список!) и потом просто знак меняем. И мне очевидно, как бы на самом деле компилятор мог сделать это в два прохода. Но три?  Но и сама формулировка " потом найти в списке элемент, номер которого соответствует разности" мне непонятна. Зачем искать? нам же просто разность нужно.

Comment: Так это же список и у нас нет итератора с произвольным доступом. Чтобы получить итератор на произвольный элемент, придется топать от начала списка и до элемента.